# How do I create an agent with a "code" parameter in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm creating an AnyLogic Agent that I'd like to frequently re-use. In many AnyLogic agents and components, there's are spaces where you can type in code like "on receive" or "Action" or "function body". These are compiled into the Agent when the model is built. How does the average programmer do this?

For example, suppose I have this Agent (pseudocode, obviously):

```
Button extends Agent
  name : Parameter  // A normal parameter for recording the button's name.
  color : Parameter // A normal parameter for recording the button's color.
  onPress : <code>  // User-provided code that is executed when the button is pressed.
```

A client might use it as follows:

```
userButton7 is a Button 
  name = "Emergency Button"
  color = Red
  onPress = {
     for each Person p in simulation
         p.tryToEscapeBuilding()
  }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write your own Agent (as a plain Java class) which includes elements in the AnyLogic model-building UI, if that's what you mean (plus, if you write your own Java class which extends Agent, you have to know the correct signatures to use for the two required constructors, which you can see from looking at the code generated for other Agents).

But, in AnyLogic 7, you can design an Agent visually and then use a limited form of inheritance to create subclasses of this Agent. (See the AnyLogic help on Agent Inheritance under Agent Based Modeling.) The inheritance is limited in that:

- you can override/overload methods (functions)---i.e., define one with the same name in a subclass---but you can't do the same for fields (variables/parameters), even if they are private in the superclass (so even for cases when it wouldn't be hiding/shadowing the field in a Java sense);
- you can't use such a subclass Agent as the top-level Agent in your model.

[Thanks to nikolaj for pointing out that function overrides are possible. I could have sworn I tried that in the initial AnyLogic 7 release and it had the same restriction as for parameters/variables; maybe it got changed in one of the 7.0.x point releases?]

Both of these can be pretty restrictive dependent on the circumstances but, in your example, this would be fine: have an Agent which has/'is' a button (with AnyLogic parameters for color, name, etc.).

Note that your onPress pseudo-code is problematic for a reusable Agent unless you do something like having a `List<? extends Person>` as a parameter for your Agent (so that, when created, it has a generic reference to something that allows it to loop through Agents with a `tryToEscapeBuilding` function).

Answer (score 0):

as monsieurRigsby says, you can create a subclass of the Agent class.
but it is actually possible to override functions.
just write: 
   @Override 
in the "Custom modifiers" of the onPress function

Comment: What is a "custom modifier"? I've never heard this term before in regards to AnyLogic.

Comment: Ah, interesting; I need to have a play with that. (You still miss out on stuff like abstract methods, though you could approximate it with a superclass method (function) which creates an exception saying that it needs to be overridden.) I'm pretty sure you can't shadow fields though (it won't let you add fields with the same name), although that is less useful in general.

Comment: @monsieurRigsby, i'm not sure what you mean by "shadow fields", but you can override: methods, parameters, variables, etc with the same name in the super-class

Comment: @Nikolaj I just double-checked and you definitely can't for fields (variables and parameters). Trying to add one with the same name gives a 'duplicate name' error. Are you doing it some 'clever' way? P.S. Shadowing is the Java terminology since defining fields with the same name is *different* to the same thing for methods: the latter overrides (in that it is not possible to call the superclass-version directly from a subclass instance) whereas the former shadows (the superclass field *can* still be accessed).

Comment: Plus, after testing it, you can override without requiring the custom modifier (which makes sense because that's how it works in Java; @override is annotation which, during compilation, double-checks that you *are*, in fact, overriding a method but you don't *need* to put it). Will edit my answer and acknowledge your point.

Comment: @monsieurRigsby I see what you mean... and you are right about the var & par. Then again there is probably not any use cases for that, since you can just redefine the value in the subclass.

Anylogic is a bit weird sometimes when you are trying to override, it often rename your method :-)